# Convert 2 digit hex op code format into 6 binary digit opcode

Tags: hex, mips, opcode, mips32

I was going through an old exam paper and was doing a question to convert `sw $6, -4($7)` into machine code in hex.

I was used to the format where the opcode is 6 digits long and set. If you Google, the opcode for `sw` is 101011. However, in this exam paper, it had a table of opcodes where the opcode was `Ox2B` which for me translates as `0010 1010`. Now, if I was to see this exam question, how would I convert this 8 digit opcode into the 6 digit one I need? What is the rule system for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made an error in your translation: `0x2B` translate to `0010 1011` (so indeed opcode `10 1011`), not `0010 1010`.